# Visa query: Travel to Athens (Greece) and Sofia (Bulgaria)

Tags: visas, customs-and-immigration, paperwork, bulgaria, schengen-visas

I am planning to travel to Greece (Athens) and Sofia (Bulgaria). I understand that I can travel to Sofia also under my Schengen visa, but I have questions:

1. Do I need to request for a multiple-entry or single-entry Schengen visa (tourist visa)?
2. Can I fly into Bulgaria (from  India) and then move to Greece and then out of Greece to India?
3. Or do I have to fly to Greece and then only can visit Bulgaria?

Answer (score 1):

As stated in Timatic, the database used by airlines:

> Visa required [for Bulgaria], **except** for passengers with a C visa issued by Croatia, Cyprus, Romania
>     or a Schengen Member State valid for the
>     period of intended stay. They are visa exempt for a maximum
>     stay of 90 days

So your Schengen visa only needs to be valid. It doesn't matter if you used it to enter the Schengen Area before Bulgaria or not.

So:

1. Single-entry is enough.
2. Yes, you can visit Bulgaria first if you want.